# Setting Up "Outbound SSL" in JBoss and/or underlying JRE

Tags: ssl, jakarta-ee, jboss, outbound

Looking to port **Outbound SSL configuration from Websphere to JBoss**.   In my case, JBoss is the client.  It wants to pass a client cert to a remote machine as part of a 2-way SSL communication.

In Websphere, you explicitly specify...

- keystore / keystore password   (where are the certs?)
- certificate alias              (which client cert to apply?)
- matching outbound url pattern  (when do i apply the client cert?)

You may have many of these configurations.   Between these 3 pieces of info, the container can selectively choose when/which client certificate to include when making **outbound** SSL calls.

1. What is the JBoss way of doing the same thing as I described above ?
2. Can this be done by simply configuring your JRE ?
3. Are there parts of this that cannot be done in JBoss and/or java?

Thanks,
Wade.

Comment: were you able to find a solution?